# Why "gulp-jest" is failing with: "Please run node with the --harmony flag!"?

Tags: gulp, reactjs, jestjs, gulp-jest

I get the following error when running `gulp test`:

```
Error: Please run node with the --harmony flag!
```

Here is my gulp task:

```
var jest = require('gulp-jest');

gulp.task('test', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/**/__tests__').pipe(jest({
    rootDir: 'src',
    scriptPreprocessor: '../node_modules/6to5-jest',
    unmockedModulePathPatterns: [ 'react' ]
  }));
});
```

To reproduce: https://github.com/SEEK-Jobs/react-playground

Note that `npm test` works properly (test is failing as expected), but `gulp test` fails with the error above. Both `npm test` and `gulp test` have the same config object:

```
{
  rootDir: 'src',
  scriptPreprocessor: '../node_modules/6to5-jest',
  unmockedModulePathPatterns: [ 'react' ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to do what error says?

Comment: I'd like to understand why the error appears with `gulp test` but not with `npm test`. Any ideas?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in `gulp-eslint`, and it is fixed now in version 0.3.0.

Comment: I experienced the same bug without `gulp-eslint` installed, so looks like it's something else. See my issue at https://github.com/Dakuan/gulp-jest/issues/9. (Btw: @steff's answer works.)

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell the error is thrown from `jest-cli`.

The reason you don't get it with `npm test` is that you probably configured npm to run the jest bin script directly, which uses [harmonize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/harmonize) to programmatically set the `--harmony` flag.

You can fix by installing harmonize and putting `require('harmonize')()` in your gulpfile.