# How to run gulp with --harmony flag?

Tags: node.js, gulp, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

The same could be achieved in node.js using `--harmony` flag like this:

```
node --harmony app.js
```

So it will be add support for EcmaScript6.

How to run gulp commands with harmony flag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why "gulp-jest" is failing with: "Please run node with the --harmony flag!"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315796/why-gulp-jest-is-failing-with-please-run-node-with-the-harmony-flag)

Comment: Usually one can achieve something like that by `gulp [options for gulp] -- --harmony`, where everything after `--` should be passed to Node.js .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simpler solution would be to use harmonize : https://github.com/dcodeIO/node-harmonize

Just install harmonize and then require like so:
`require("harmonize")();`

Answer (score 5):

You can do that in the following way:

```
alias gulp='node --harmony `which gulp`'
```

Place this in `~/.bashrc` file and gulp will always run in harmony mode.

If you are a docker user and want to use `gulp` with harmony inside a container, you can do that in the following way:

```
docker run -ti \
    --name container \
    nodejs-image-with-gulp-pre-installed \
    bash -ci 'gulp task'
```

The key is to use `-i` flag with a bash, so your alias will be loaded successfully. Otherwise it will run gulp itself without harmony support.

Comment: You can't just name the alias the same way, the command you try to resolve (`which gulp`) is named. This should end up in an error, since `which gulp` will resolve to ``gulp: aliased to node --harmony `which gulp` ``

Comment: @naeramarth7 thanks for the reply. Yeah I also was thought about that but actualy `which gulp` even after an alias, returns the actual path to a gulp binary. You can check it by your own, it is just works.

Comment: checked that beforehand - does not work in `zsh` on `OS X 10.10` (besides the missing quote on the alias line). Gives me `Error: Cannot find module '<path to current folder>/gulp'` since it tries to run exactly this command: ``node --harmony gulp: aliased to node --harmony `which gulp` ``.

Comment: It worked for me with no problems - both for `gulp any-task` commands and vanilla `gulp`. I ran it in GNOME terminal 3.6.2, on 64-bit Linux Mint 17.1.

Answer (score 3):

To follow up on FelikZ's solution:

**npm run**

You can update your `package.json` and add your gulp commands to the section `scripts`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --harmony `which gulp` start",
    "build": "node --harmony `which gulp` build",
    ...
  }
}
```

These commands can then be called with `npm run start`, `npm run build` etc.

If you want to call all your gulp commands through npm (without defining them separately) you can do as follows:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "gulp": "node --harmony `which gulp`"
  }
}
```

To run `gulp start`, you would call `npm run -- start` etc.

**Alternative: io.js**

If you want to use `--harmony` by default, you could also have a look at io.js:

https://iojs.org/en/es6.html